# codeigniter error using JOIN to select single row

Tags: codeigniter

Im trying to get joins to work when selecting a single row. here is my code:

model:

```
          function view($id) {
            $this->db->select('c.name
                                ,c.phone
                                ,c.active
                                ,c.website
                                ,c.date_acquired
                                ,con.firstName');
            $this->db->from('company c');
            $this->db->join('contacts con','c.primary_contact = con.id','left');
            $this->db->where('id', $id);
            $query = $this->db->get();
            return $query->row_array();
```

controller:

```
public function view($id)
{

    $this->load->model('Company_model');
    $data['data']= $this->Company_model->view($id);
    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('company/view', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');

}
```

the error im getting is:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function row_array() on a non-object in
>   /home/techf/public_html/application/models/company_model.php on line
>   35

and line 35 in the above code is:

```
$query = $this->db->get()
```

is this not correct when dealing with joins and a row array?

**

### edit 1

**:

Here is my controller:

```
public function view($id)
{

    $this->load->model('Company_model');
    $data = $this->Company_model->view($id)->row();
    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('company/view', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');

}
```

and my model:

```
function view($id) {
            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('company');
            $this->db->join('contacts con','c.primary_contact = con.id','left');
            $this->db->where('id', $id);
            return $this->db->get('company');
 }
```

but now im am getting error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function row() on a non-object in
>   /home/techf/public_html/application/controllers/company.php on line 21

Comment: are you getting result? i guess the query is returning empty set

Comment: `$data = $this->Company_model->view($id)->row();` r u sure it should be like this . I think this should be `$data = $this->Company_model->view($id);`

Comment: Rakesh, i agree, someone asked me to try that. I updated my question to reflect the code i currently am using.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go model code

```
        public function get_joins($table,$value,$joins,$where,$order_by,$order)
    {
        $this->db->select($value);
         if (is_array($joins) && count($joins) > 0)
          {
             foreach($joins as $k => $v)
               {
                $this->db->join($v['table'], $v['condition'], $v['jointype']);
               }
          }
         $this->db->order_by($order_by,$order);
         $this->db->where($where);
        return $this->db->get($table);
     }




    and in your controller aceess it like

   $value=('restaurantorders.*,restaurant.Name,restaurant.CurrencyId,currency.*,orderpaymentdetail.Gateway ');
        $joins = array
        (
                  array
                (
                  'table' => 'tk_restaurant',
                  'condition' => 'restaurant.Id = restaurantorders.RestaurantId',
                  'jointype' => 'inner'
                 ),
                  array
                (
                  'table' => 'tk_currency',
                  'condition' => 'restaurant.CurrencyId = currency.Id',
                  'jointype' => 'inner'
                 ),
                   array
                (
                  'table' => 'tk_orderpaymentdetail',
                  'condition' => 'restaurantorders.Id = orderpaymentdetail.OrderId',
                  'jointype' => 'inner'
                 ),
        );

        $data['order_detail'] = $this->general_model->get_joins($data['tbl'],$value,$joins,array('OrderStatus'=>'Confirm','restaurantorders.Id'=>$orderid),'restaurantorders.Id','desc')->row();
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, getting an error, see my edited question with an updated controller and model

Comment: just edit call to method like this
<code>$data['result']=$this->yourmodelname->view($id)->row();</code>


you can accees via $result in view

Comment: i changed to: $data['result']= $this->Company_model->view($id)->row();
<br/> 
but same error

Comment: do one thing change your table name ...make it wrong like....companys...and refresh the page so it will throw error like no table exist named companys and print your query...copy and paste that query  in your mysql and see what result you are getting...dont forget to make your table name coorrect while you paste in mysql

Comment: you sure that syntax is right? i changed it to companys, but its throwing the same exact error.  Fatal error: Call to a member function row() on a non-object in /home/techf/public_html/application/controllers/company.php on line 21

Comment: by the way, line 21 on company.php is this line:  $data['result']= $this->Company_model->view($id)->row();

Comment: Yeah..i am sure about syntex ...i am posting my code for your referance edit it as per your requirenment...

Answer (score 0):

**note** that on the model i test first if `num_rows()` is greater than 1 before sending on the `row` and if not return  `false`.

**Note** that on my `this->db->get` i removed the name of the table, because you already added it on the from method.

```
        $this->db->select('*')
                ->from('company c');
                ->join('contacts con','c.primary_contact = con.id','left');
                ->where('id', $id);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->num_rows() >= 1 ? $query->row() : FALSE;
```

on your **COntroller**
on on the `data` variable you forgot to add a `key`, this will be used when you access the variable/object on you're view, example is `$data['contacts']`

```
public function view($id)
{

    $this->load->model('Company_model');
    $data['contacts'] = $this->Company_model->view($id);
    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('company/view', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');

}
```

on your **VIEWS**
access the `contacts` key that you assigned earlier on you're controller.

```
<?
 if(!empty($contacts))
{
   print_r($contacts);
}else{
   echo 'No data';
}


?>
```

to show the structure of your query on a standard MySQL query

you could comment out the `return` on you're model and add this snippets of code just after the `$this->db->get()` method.

```
echo $this->db->last_query();
die();
```

This will echo out what query was made, and you can run it on `phpmyadmin` and compare if the values returned are right.

Answer (score 0):

can you try it like this maybe?

model: (i'm not sure in which table is id and in which primary_contact, so change that if i made a mistake)

```
function view($id) {
    $this->db->join('contacts','company.primary_contact = contacts.id','left')
        ->where('id', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get('company');
    return $query->row();
}
```

in controller call it like this:

```
$data['result'] = $this->company_model->view($id);
```

then access object in view:

```
<?=$result->id?> (etc.)
```

Comment: same error as all the others: Fatal error: Call to a member function row() on a non-object in /home/techf/public_html/application/models/company_model.php on line 31

Comment: are you sure u have records in database, and that the names are correct?